# TreeView is not clickable inside div tag in asp dot net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using treeView in my application.
the HTML design is as follows

```
  <div class="left">
        <div id="locations">
           <asp:TreeView ID="tvLocationView" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" ShowLines="true"
SelectedNodeStyle-Font-Bold="true" SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="Green"
                runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvLocationView_SelectedNodeChanged" Width="200px">

            </asp:TreeView>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my c# code is

```
enter code here

TreeNode child = new TreeNode
                {
                    Text = "PARENT",
                    Value = "PARENT"
                };
                tvLocationView.Nodes.Add(child);


                MSSQLHelper.SqlCon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlconString"].ToString();
                DataSet ds = MSSQLHelper.ExecSqlDataSet("SP_GetAllData", CommandType.StoredProcedure, new List<SqlParameter>()
                {
                });
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode
                        {
                            Text = dtrow["LOCATIONNAME"].ToString(),
                            Value = dtrow["LOCATIONNUMBER"].ToString()
                        };

                        child1.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
                        child.ChildNodes.Add(child1);

                    }
                }
```

if i remove div class="left" this tag then i can click on any child nodes. but in the above code, I am not able to click all child nodes.
can anyone help me out to solve this issue

Comment: .left { float: left; padding-right: 3px;
    width: 264px;
    height: 100px;
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am new and I cannot comment I will leave it as an answer:

You have the class code of the "left" style, if you can share it to be able to mislead the causes of the error.
As a suggestion you can try adding the Z-index with negative value to the class.

Comment: .left { float: left; padding-right: 3px;
    width: 264px;
    height: 100px;
}this is .left css

Comment: You have tried changing the value of the Z-index? , like this example:
 
.left { float: left; padding-right: 3px; width: 264px; height: 100px;  z-index: -1;}

Comment: Yes.. i have created 2 different css classes for left . now it is working fine.